# get back directories deleted on hfs+ filesystem

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, data-recovery, hfs+

Anyone knows if it is easy "get back" a directory in hfsplus file system, mounted to Linux and deleted by rm?

Long story short, I connected my iPad to Ubuntu (14.04) and wanted to import my pictures.

I used ifuse to mount it, I'm not sure how exactly ifuse did it, may be somethings similar to

```
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdx# /media/binchen/ipad
ifuse /media/binchen/ipad
```

Then, I made a mistake I'm now trying to fix...

```
rm -rf /media/binchen/ipad/DCIM,
```

If there is an easy way to bring it back? I feel this is file system dependent and hope hfs+ filesystem has some superior features here..but I know nothing about it.

Is this some thing can be done?

Answer (score 0):

HFS+ in itself has no protection against `rm -rf` as you bypassed any safeguards.

If this were on a regular hard drive or even SSD, & as you bypassed the Trash, then you would be down to your favourite recovery software to scrape the drive for file remnants.

As you did this on a hardware encrypted device which was never designed to be poked at by the user at folder level, then I think you're right out of luck.
Restoring the iPad to its last backup will be your only option.